WMware Player with Intel Core i7-13700H?
I consider buying a laptop with Intel Core i7-13700H, but I can't find any compatibility data for VMware Player.
Does anyone know if it will work together?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I want to know if WMware Player will work on system with Intel Core i7-13700H processor.

@JankoJanjic - Yes; Of course it is compatible. VMWare is comaptaible on all Intel and AMD x86 processors. Intel Virtualization Hardware (VT-x) isn't necessarily required to run VMWare.  Core i7-13700H does support VT-x

Correct VT-x isn't required to run the VMWare Player iteself, but you will find VT-x IS required to run 64-bit guest systems on the Player. So it depends on which Guest OS' Janko wants to run on the Player.
Hence why I posted the links to where Janko can find the info for himself.
Teach a man to fish...

@cb2791 - I am aware of the accuracy of my statement.  VT-x is NOT required to run a 64-bit guest on a 64-bit host.

The Host System Requirements for VMWare Workstation Player are listed here:
Host System Requirements for Workstation Player
From that page, if you follow the link for Supported Processors, you will find which processors are supported.
